# How can I get the modified wave number with sum of cosine functions?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

I learned that a modified wave number, $k'$, is the number that satisfies the following condition

$$f'_j = ik'f_j$$

However, there is a problem while I estimate a modified number of the below function

$$f(x) = 5 \cos(x) + \cos(10x)$$

I used the first order forward difference. So, I estimated the modified number like

\begin{align}
f'_j &\approx \frac{f_{j+1} - f_j}{h} \\
&= \frac{5(\cos(x+h) - \cos(x)) + \cos(10(x+h)) - \cos(10x)}{h} \\
&= \frac{-10 \sin \left(x + \frac{h}{2} \right) \sin \left(\frac{h}{2} \right) - 2 \sin(10x+5h) \sin(5h)}{h}
\end{align}

Then, I don't know how to rearrange RHS in order to get the form $5 \cos(x) + \cos(10x)$. Is my approach correct? or, Do I have to use other approach?

Comment: Is $i$ the imaginary number?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't specify it

Comment: Isn't $f_{j} = f(x_{j})$ i.e $f$ evaluated at the grid point $x_{j}$?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for confusing.